# phpmailer stop sending emails after sending one email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hi I am using phpmailer 5.2 on ubuntu , I simply download the zip file extract it and upload the folder to my project folder. It working fine when send the first email but after sending one email it stops sending emails with connection time out error. Then maybe after half or one hour can send one email again and again it will stop working .This is the code:

require_once('path/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.abc.com"; // SMTP servers change to localhost
$mail->Smtp_port ="465";       // change smtp port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "admin@abc.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "abc"; // SMTP password
        $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";   
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->AddAddress($to);


$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $body;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
            $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 

            //echo $error;

            return $error;
}
        else{

            $error = 'Message sent!';

           // echo $error;

            return $error;

        }
```

I get this error: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)The following From address failed: admin@abc.com : Called Mail() without being connected.

I stuck on this for 3 days already. I do not know how what is wrong. I will be very grateful if someone can help.thanks

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave no my problem is different, I can send one email successfully then it will stop sending emails for awhile  and then can send one email again. it like one email can send, then it will stop sending emails for about half hour (less/more), then again can send one email.

Comment: See my answer on GitHub, but it could be your ISP doing extreme throttling.

Comment: @Synchro yes I have checked your answer on github. your answer fixed my problem. thank you so much. for everyone else who might have the same problem,  my problem was using  $mail->Smtp_port ="465"; I must use $mail->Port ="465"; according to Synchro There’s no such property as Smtp_port. If you want to set the port, do this: $mail->Port .

Comment: Minor thing, but it’s an integer, not a string, so you don’t need the quotes either.